# Remesh modifier hits cpu instead gpu and crashes

Tags: gpu

Adding the remesh modifier and increasing the voxel amount first triggers the cpu going up to 100% and then crashes blender. I've set CUDA in preferences and GPU for cycles, which otherwise work.

How can I set the GPU for just *everything* in blender and rule out the cpu?

Answer (score 4):

> How can I set the GPU for just everything in blender and rule out the cpu?

Actually, most of the algorithm, operation, modifier, complex computing, data handling is done by CPU, not GPU.

Although Rendering can be **accelerated** by GPU, but those code is rewrite/design for GPU by developer. Migrating any algorithm to GPU instruction can take a lot of effort due to the lack of some ability and the difference of hard structure. Also, only some algorithm will benefit from GPU.

**Remeshing** is a complex topic in CG, the new method adopted by Blender is not transferred to GPU code for now. There is nothing Blender can do for you, unless you could develop a GPU accelerated Remeshing algorithm for it.

Algorithm and GPU coding is not that easy as you described.